# What are Carnot groups?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, manifolds, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to learn the Pansu differentiability theorem and I need to know what Carnot groups are. Can someone please explain what Carnot groups are? An introductory reference would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thanks.

Comment: An intersting blog https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/lecture-16-free-carnot-groups/

Answer (score 0):

A Carnot group is a special type of Lie group $\mathcal{G} $ that is nilpotent (almost abelian) and simply connected. Its Lie algebra $\mathcal{g}$ gives a nilpotent stratification consisting of $k$ steps. This can be represented in the form $\mathcal{V}_1\oplus\cdots \oplus \mathcal{V}_k$ with $[\mathcal{V}_1,\mathcal{V}_m]=\mathcal{V}_{1+m},~m=1,\cdots ,k-1$. For example, the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the binary operation of addition is a commutative Carnot group. Carnot groups possess a Carnot-Caratheodory metric (a metric space with integer Hausdorff dimension greater than its dimension) and Pansu derivative (a special type of derivative adapted to a Carnot group).

Comment: I suppose you will say "with $[\mathcal{V}_1,\mathcal{V}_m]=\mathcal{V}_{1+m},~m=1,\cdots ,k-1$"

Answer (score 0):

I am reading them from a Doctoral Thesis:
Distances, boundaries and surface
measures in Carnot-Carath´eodory spaces
Roberto Monti

However, without the first 20 pages of "Hardy spaces on homogeneous groups, G.B. Folland and E.M. Stein" I would have had a difficult time understanding the whole picture.