# Carnot group example

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Can someone please help me to understand if the Euclidean space $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$ with pointwise addition structure is a Carnot group according to the Wikipedia definition:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_group

What I could verify is that $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$ is a Nilpotent Lie group, but unable to understand if the Lie algebra (which I hope is $(R^n,+)$ itself here) can be written as a direct sum according to the definition in the above link. If so, then it should be a Carnot group.

Can someone please help me with the same?

I appreciate your time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108352/what-are-carnot-groups), with $\mathcal{V}_k$ for $k$-step nilpotent. So $k=1$ for the abelian case.

Comment: What do you mean by $k=1$ for the Abelian case? Can you please elaborate? $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$ is also Abelian.

Comment: Yes, exactly. A $k$-step nilpotent Lie algebra is abelian if and only if $k=1$. Hence $\Bbb R^n$ is a $1$-step nilpotent Lie algebra (which is called "abelian").

Comment: Is every Abelian group a Carnot group?

Comment: I sense a cyclic comment thread developing... The first comment has already answered your last comment, @Mathguide.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused. Hope its clear now. Thanks.